# write new dataframe as csv file on an old one

Tags: r

I have a data frame, str(data) to show more about my data frame the result is the following:

```
data.frame': 569 obs. of 16 variables:
$ Age : int 42 42 25 53 54 66 55 54 54 53 ...
$ Primary_Site : int 4 4 2 1 2 4 4 1 1 2 ...
$ Histology : int NA NA NA 1 2 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ Tumor_Size : num NA NA 2.7 4 3 3 2 1 1 5 ...
```

I extract some rows with below code that create new dataframe:

```
df[df$Tumor_Size < 8,]
```

However, when I want to write the result of above code as CSV file with:

```
write.csv(df, file = "df.csv")
```

The CSV file is old dataframe and doesn’t contain new dataframe. What is problem?

Comment: `df <- df[df$Tumor_Size < 8,]` before you save it. You have to reassign it because it doesn't change by reference.

Comment: Or `write.csv(df[df$Tumor_Size < 8,], file = "df.csv")` if you don't want to overwrite `df`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answers were key.